# "undefined symbol" error while running JNI_CreateJavaVM function in Apache module

Tags: c, jvm, apache-modules

I would like to init JVM in Apache module via `ap_hook_pre_config` fun but when I run XAMPP, this error occurs:

> XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
>
> httpd: Syntax error on line 158 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_hotcup.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_hotcup.so: undefined symbol: JNI_CreateJavaVM

It's strange because it compiles normally.

Any ideas what is missed?

I use Ubuntu 18, Java 11. Here's source code [mod_hotcup.c](https://pastecode.xyz/view/c8cf0fff)

Comment: How do you build `mod_hotcup.c`? (don't you forget to link to a library like `jvm`?)

Comment: TBH I even didn't know that I have to link it, my build.sh file: https://pastecode.xyz/view/5530b41a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the arguments order when invoking `ld`:

Libraries to link must after the code to link.

Instead of

```
ld -Bshareable -o mod_hotcup.so mod_hotcup.o
```

It should be

```
ld -Bshareable -o mod_hotcup.so mod_hotcup.o -L${LIBPATH} -ljvm
```